# How to know and fix fails or errors in randomly down ipsec tunnel connection?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have a server connected by VPN site to site with strongswan (first time with VPN), when I start the connection (`sudo ipsec up my-conn`) all work good but in some point the server lost the connection ( the conn can stay good for many days).

Has far as I know the log is in `/var/log/syslog` but I do not know what I need to looking for. Also I do not know the correct log level [(doc)](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/LoggerConfiguration)

I execute `ipsec statusall` before and after restart the connection (`ipsec down my-conn` and `ipsec up my-conn`) and the only difference is:

BEFORE

```
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):    
    my-conn[436]: ESTABLISHED 22 hours ago,     XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]...XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 
    my-conn[436]: IKEv1 SPIs: d35f055913e29a30_i* c8078f3f7ba8a865_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 93 minutes
    my-conn[436]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
```

AFTER

```
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   my-conn[438]: ESTABLISHED 3 seconds ago, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]...XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
   my-conn[438]: IKEv1 SPIs: e9151397cc30bf0f_i* 28bc636791f3c2d3_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 23 hours
   my-conn[438]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024
   my-conn{2469}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 31, ESP SPIs: c307472a_i 4a690618_o
   my-conn{2469}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA1_96, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 42 minutes
   my-conn{2469}:   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/16 === XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/16
```

Comment: Could you show the charon log with the default level for now?

Comment: @grawity this is `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: I can not get the log of the last day of fail, when occur I will post the log of `syslog`